# Have there been more US CDS curve inversions since 2011, and do these correlate with (political) disputes around the debt ceiling?

Tags: government-debt, political-economy

Gori [proposes](https://voxeu.org/article/lessons-2011-us-debt-ceiling-crisis) a model of the 2011 US debt ceiling crisis in which the spread (and ultimately inversion) of the US government credit default swaps (1Y/2Y vs 5Y) is used as a proxy measure for the seriousness of the event, as perceived by the market.

Although the articles were published many years later (2018-2021) I'm not seeing a discussion of whether the CDS curve inversion model extrapolates well to other political standoffs around the US debt ceiling. So were there more of these that correlate with other political crises/standoff on the debt ceiling?